# When using ' ios::sync_with_stdio(0)' for testing difference in runtime, why is my output fragmented?

Tags: c++, printf, cin

```
  clock_t tStart = clock();
  ios::sync_with_stdio(0);
  cin.tie(0);
  for(int i=0;i<100000;++i) cout<<i;
  printf("\n\n\n\nTime taken: %.2fs\n", (double)(clock() - tStart)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
  cout<<endl;
```

Using this program with cout runs in 4.05 seconds but outputs some numbers even after it executes final line. Here's the details:

```
Time taken: 4.30s
99924999259992699927999289992999930999319993299933999349993599936999379993899939999409994199942999439994499945999469994799948999499995099951999529995399954999559995699957999589995999960999619996299963999649996599966999679996899969999709997199972999739997499975999769997799978999799998099981999829998399984999859998699987999889998999990999919999299993999949999599996999979999899999
```

Using printf program runs as intended but is very slow (51 seconds). I used endl after printing time to also flush the output buffer. What's the reason for this?

Comment: Why are you mixing `printf` and `cout` at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you no longer synchronize C stdio (which `printf` uses) with the C++ stream I/O (which `std::cout` uses). That means they have different buffers that may be flushed (and written to the console) at different times.

Try adding a `std::cout << std::flush` before the `printf` call. Or better yet, use `std::cout` for the last output as well.